# Is there any plugin to integrate mercurial with IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

I am trying to find a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA to work with [*Mercurial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) distributed source control management tool, but I can't find any.

Answer (score 4):

A plug-in for [*Mercurial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) is bundled (available out of the box) in IDEA 10 and later. See the [*hg4idea*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3370-hg4idea) plugin product page.

Make sure it's enabled in `Settings`/`Preferences` | `Plugins`.

[image]

Comment: ok.i'll give it a try.I have an old version of IntelliJ IDEA 8.1.3, so i was searching for something unbundled